# Drupal console: The "--shellexec_output" option does not exist

Tags: drupal

Since a recent drupal 8 update my drupal console no longer works even after reinitializing the project, upgrading composer, etc.

Drupal Console version:
1.0.0-beta5
command:
drupal generate:module
Drupal version
8.1.1
but also 8.2.x

error message:
[Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\RuntimeException]
  The "--shellexec_output" option does not exist.

Can anyone help here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Remove the line with `shellexec_output: true` from `~/.console/config.yml` (probably the last line in the file).

Source: https://github.com/hechoendrupal/DrupalConsole/issues/2782

Comment: @jmux As you says that this works for you should check the answer as acepted.